# Partial doesn't render when using 'enter' in HTML

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an Ajax call when DOM is loaded:

`/assets/javascript/items.js`:

```
if ($('#content-recommendation').length) {
    xhr = $.ajax({
    url:'/get_recommendations/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
    type:"get"
  });
}
```

`views/items/show`:

```
<div id="content-recommendation" class="col-md-3">
  <p>hey!</p>
</div>
```

`items_controller#get_recommendation`:

```
def get_recommendations
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end
```

`items/get_recommendations.js.erb`:

```
$("#content-recommendation").html("<%= render 'content_recommendation'%>")
```

`_content_recommendation.html.erb`:

```
<h3>Last Visited Items:</h3>
<p>test</p>
```

This is by far, the strange thing I saw in RoR. If I put in `_content_recommendation.html.erb`:

```
<h3Last Visited Items:</h3><p>test</p>
```

(without spaces) It works!!

Answer (score 0):

For lack of other answers, perhaps you'd prefer to try the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :items do
   get "get_recommendations/:id", action: :get_recommendations, on: :collection
end

#app/assets/javascripts/items.js
if $('#content-recommendation').length {
    $.ajax({
      url:'/get_recommendations/' + gon.item_id,
  });
}

#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController 
    def get_recommendations
       respond_to do |format|
          format.js
       end
    end
end

#app/views/items/get_recommendations.js.erb
$("#content-recommendation").html("<%=j render partial 'content_recommendation' %>");
```